# How to count mouse clicks?

Tags: javascript

```
var number = 1;
var mouseClicked = function() {
```

How do I make a mouseClick add +1 when the mouse is clicked? and another +1 when it's pressed again, etc etc. I'm new and have searched all over the place hoping to find this specific problem somewhere with an explanation.

I started learning JavaScript today and am trying to create a stop light effect on 3 lights, #1 = Green, #2 = Yellow and #3 = Red. When I click I want it to advance the number and in doing so advance the color to the next light. I can't figure out how to make it add numbers though.

```
 = 1
*mouseClick*
 = 2
*mouseClick*
 = 3
```

etc, etc.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: when the screen is pressed ???

Comment: Likes so: `number += 1;`. Addition should really be covered by a tutorial though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<button onClick="mouseClicked()">add number</button>
```

**Javascript**

```
var number = 1;
var mouseClicked = function() {
  console.log('mouseClick = ' + number);
  number++;
}
```

**Output**

-Screen

[image: Screen]

-Console

[image: Console]

[PLAYGROUND](http://codepen.io/raunay/pen/Ibxho)

Comment: I think it's more logical for *number* to start at 0, then be incremented before being displayed so `...('mouseclick = ' + ++number)`, so at any time, *number* represents the number of clicks that have occured.

Comment: well, in this case 'mouseClick' means the total number of clicks added after the interaction. Otherwise, you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a listener to the window or to the document

```
 var number = 0;
    function addOne()
    {
        number += 1;
        console.log(number);
    }
    window.addEventListener('click', addOne, false); //document.addEventListener('click', addOne, false); should work too
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the number on the screen in a span with an ID ( `<span id='mynum'></span>` ) then use this to update the number:

```
var mynum = 1;
var mouseClicked = function() {
    mynum ++;
    document.getElementById('mynum').innerHTML = mynum
}
```

Then use the ID of the button to set a listener:

```
document.getElementById('buttonID').onclick = mouseclicked;
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you are using javascript in a web-application:

some-file.html

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Click Counter</title>
</head>
<body>
    clicks counted:<span id='clicks'>0</span>
    <script>

            var number = 0;

            document.onclick = function(){
                    number ++;
                    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = number;
            }               

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Copy and paste this code to a HTML file, and run in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
   <body>
      <button id="b1" onclick="getValue()">click and getcounts</button>
      <script>
         var i=0;
         //initially i is 0. When button clicked, function increments 'i' value.
         function getValue(){
            i++;
            var j=i;
            alert(j);
         }
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```